# Silverlight Image Panning

Tags: silverlight

I am working on silverlight application and I had use the  pixel shadder with brightness and contrast which is working fine. so I had tried with panning center x,y but it will not working so how I can add this panning.

My PS file like this.

```
    /// <class>briconEffect</class>

/// <description>An effect that controls brightness and contrast.</description>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Shader constant register mappings (scalars - float, double, Point, Color, Point3D, etc.)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/// <summary>The brightness offset.</summary>
/// <minValue>-1</minValue>
/// <maxValue>1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
float Brightness : register(C0);

/// <summary>The contrast multiplier.</summary>
/// <minValue>0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>2</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1.5</defaultValue>
float Contrast : register(C1);

/// <summary>The gamma correction exponent.</summary>
/// <minValue>0.5</minValue>
/// <maxValue>2</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0.8</defaultValue>
float Gamma : register(C2);

/// <summary>Change the ratio between the Red channel</summary>
/// <minValue>0/minValue>
/// <maxValue>1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0.5</defaultValue>
float RedRatio : register(C3);

/// <summary>Change the ratio between the Blue channel </summary>
/// <minValue>0/minValue>
/// <maxValue>1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0.5</defaultValue>
float BlueRatio : register(C4);

/// <summary>Change the ratio between the Green channel</summary>
/// <minValue>0/minValue>
/// <maxValue>1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0.5</defaultValue>
float GreenRatio : register(C5);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sampler Inputs (Brushes, including Texture1)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sampler2D Texture1Sampler : register(S0);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pixel Shader
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 pixelColor = tex2D(Texture1Sampler, uv);

    pixelColor.rgb = pow(pixelColor.rgb, Gamma);

    pixelColor.rgb /= pixelColor.a;

    // Apply contrast.
    pixelColor.rgb = ((pixelColor.rgb - 0.5f) * max(Contrast, 0)) + 0.5f;

    // Apply brightness.
    pixelColor.rgb += Brightness;

    // Return final pixel color.
    pixelColor.rgb *= pixelColor.a;


    pixelColor.r = pixelColor.r * (1-RedRatio ) ;
    pixelColor.b = pixelColor.b * (1-BlueRatio ) ;
    pixelColor.g = pixelColor.g * (1-GreenRatio ) ;

    return pixelColor;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a StackOverflow question to me.  Their source code formatting even works.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been migrated, not closed?

Comment: @Evan: Unfortunately, the "off topic" vote here only lists meta as an alternative place where the question could/would be topical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight Image Panning.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762255/silverlight-image-panning)